# How does this song lyric "Simple and Clean" scan?

Tags: song-lyrics, meter

From the English version of ["Simple and Clean"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UigzN-4JR14) by Utada Hikaru:

> When you walk away
>    You don't hear me say
>    Please, O baby, don't go
>    Simple and clean is the way that you're making me feel tonight
>    It's hard to let it go

I couldn't structure the fourth line into verses because I don't have a sense of the meter. What type of poetic meter is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line scans like this:

```
 /   x x     /   x    x  /    x   x      / x    x  /    x /
Simple and clean is the way that you're making me feel tonight
```

so one way to describe this would be “[catalectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalectic) [dactylic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactyl_(poetry)) [hexameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexameter) with a [trochee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee) in the penultimate foot”. But really the song isn’t regular enough in its rhythm for that kind of prosodic description to be useful. What you might say instead is that the song is mostly stressed on every *second* syllable:

```
  /   x   /   x /
When you walk away

/    x     /    x  /
You don't hear me say

  /    x  / x  /     x
Please O baby don't go
```

but then switches to being stressed on every *third* syllable for this line, making it stand out from the rest, appropriately enough, as it is delivering the theme and title of the song.